# Lusztig's root datum

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

In his *"Introduction to quantum groups"*, Lusztig first defines a Cartan datum $(I,\cdot)$ and then a root datum of $(I,\cdot)$-type, which suggests (to me) that a root datum is not determined by $(I,\cdot)$. Doesn't the Cartan datum determine the root datum, at least in the Lie algebra, or more generally, in the Kac-Moody case? Is Lusztig's setup more general that that?

PS: On a broader point, are there any reasonably readable surveys of Lusztig's work in this book?